# Suspicious md5sum of /usr/bin/geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to sanity check my geth installation before unlocking my wallet.

My `geth version` on Ubuntu is

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.18-stable
Git Commit: f5382591874220287de253bfc08b10afd5244927
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.14.2
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/build/ethereum-epTfUQ/.go
```

The `md5sum /usr/bin/geth` is `3b4fef56c1cc0a357fa9524d7b295ba5`, sha1 is `9dbc9772eb4127eba6de77bda4c5e7fba2974040`.

At the moment when I visit `https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/` to check the sums I get "Retrieving packages from release server..." for ages followed by failure.

- I suspect the essential data is in [this URL](https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds?restype=container&comp=list&maxresults=5000&prefix=geth-) but if I `wget` that I get lots of "connection reset by peer" errors.
- Also the `<Content-MD5>` tags in the partial download look base64-encoded, but if I try one of them e.g. `echo "XZzyT22t79PD18TFbS5jNQ==" | base64 -d` yields nothing and `echo "XZzyT22t79PD18TFbS5jNQ" | base64 -d` yields an "invalid input" error.

When I google the above sums directly I get no results.

Based on the above version and md5sums, is my installed geth version legitimate?

How to I verify this information if `https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/` is unavailable?

Comment: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ seems to be back up, but I get different results for the same version (1.9.18-stable, Linux amd64, Git commit `f5382591874220287de253bfc08b10afd5244927`). MD5 hash of the archive: `f73bc67bddf56cad5d2e1b85fdf13f5e`, binary: `26c8b46aee5113f2c814b3f34a90de3d`.